# onOptionsItemSelected, return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) explaination

Tags: java, android

For `onOptionsItemSelected` method, this method would only be invoked if an item is clicked, right? If an item is clicked in that activity, but for some weird reason the programmer did not have the if statement to check for that item's id, does return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` enter into an infinite loop of keep calling this method?

My guess of `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` means calling the parent class and invoke this method again?

Answer (score 3):

No, it calls the parent's class method so it has a chance to run what it needs to run. If you were to use something like this.onOptionsItemSelected(item); then it would be a infinite loop.

Comment: It means parent onitemselected going to handle it best possible?